# Please interpret the contents of the Xcode memory debugger

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

A memory trick occurred during app development.

When I ran the Xcode memory debugger, I saw the image below.

Please interpret the image below.

What does the number inside the circle mean?

[image]

Comment: If you click one of the numbers, I think it’ll show you the links between the two objects in question.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the number inside the circle mean?

It is the number of retains causing the retain cycle.